kubernetes Metallb - impossible to create address pool (failed to call webhook)
I’m not sure if this is the right Stack Exchange site, so please let me know if it isn’t.
I've a loadbalancer problem in a baremetal kubernetes. I recently installed MetalLB using the following manifest:
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.13.12/config/manifests/metallb-native.yaml

I configured ipvs mode and set strictARP to true (although I'm unsure if this is mandatory, as my default configuration used the iptables proxy)
However, I encountered issues when trying to install the following IPAddressPool:
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: IPAddressPool
metadata:
  name: address-pool
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  addresses:
  - 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254

---
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: L2Advertisement
metadata:
  name: l2advertisement
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  ipAddressPools:
  - address-pool

Two webhooks seem to reject my configuration with the following errors:
kubectl apply -f ipaddresspool.yaml
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "ipaddresspool.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "l2advertisementvalidationwebhook.metallb.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://webhook-service.metallb-system.svc:443/validate-metallb-io-v1beta1-l2advertisement?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "ipaddresspool.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "ipaddresspoolvalidationwebhook.metallb.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://webhook-service.metallb-system.svc:443/validate-metallb-io-v1beta1-ipaddresspool?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded

It appears the webhooks aren't reachable. However, I have this resource:
kubectl get ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
NAME                                                   WEBHOOKS   AGE
cert-manager-webhook                                   1          37d
metallb-webhook-configuration                          6          56m

By kubectl describe this metallb-webhook-configuration, I see all the webhooks provided inside the MetalLB manifest.
By checking the logs from the MetalLB controller, I found an error indicating a certificate problem:
{
    "level": "error",
    "logger": "cert-rotation",
    "msg": "secret is not well-formed, cannot update webhook configurations",
    "error": "Cert secret is not well-formed, missing ca.crt",
    ...
}

I tried the solution proposed in this issue, which allowed the IP AddressPools to install correctly. However, the external IPs are only accessible internally. For example, I cannot curl my external IP from my master node.

Hi @guiverc , thanks for your answer. My Kubernetes setup consists of 1 master and 2 worker nodes, all running on Ubuntu 22.04 with kubeadm 1.28.2, so it's a baremetal environment. I've deployed some services and pods, and I'm trying to access them via an external IP provided by MetalLB, acting as the load balancer. For instance, I want to be able to curl one of my services directly from the master node's bash console.
